# PostgreSQL - Regression tests - SELinux

Tags: postgresql, testing, regression

After PostgreSQL installation via RPMs (RHEL 5.3), I want to make regression tests by a

```
"make check"
```

in 
    /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/test/regress according to the doc ==> /usr/share/doc/postgresql93-9.3.4/README.rpm-dist

However, I got the following errors :

```
rm -rf testtablespace results
mkdir testtablespace results
[ -x /usr/bin/chcon ] && /usr/bin/chcon -u system_u -r object_r -t postgresql_db_t      testtablespace results
/usr/bin/chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file testtablespace
/usr/bin/chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file results
make: *** [cleandirs] Erreur 1
```

It is more a Selinux problem than a PostgreSQL pb, I guess.
Any help or advice ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made it work.

The OS I work is SELinux disabled (/usr/sbin/sestatus).

1. cd /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/test/regress
2. vi Makefile
3. uncomment the following line
   [ -x /usr/bin/chcon ] && /usr/bin/chcon -u system_u -r object_r -t postgresql_db_t testtablespace results
4. save
5. make check
6. Results :

=======================

## All 136 tests passed.

Yes ! et Voilà !